# How to use different arrays for different days?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays both of sets of dates and times for a school bell schedule. The school uses a different bell schedule on Wednesdays. How do I pull the array for Wednesday only on Wednesday and allow for the other array to work on every day besides Wednesday? This code will take the start and end times in the array and if the time is between the start and end times it will take the time between the two and display a countdown timer.

```
//start of code
var d = new Date(2019);
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  return {
    'total': t,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}
var myVar;


    myVar = setInterval(function(){window.location.reload(1);}, 1000);


function myStopFunction() {
  clearTimeout(myVar);
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  clock.style.display = 'block';
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);



    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);
 }



  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);

}

var windowObjectReference;

function openRequestedPopup() {
  windowObjectReference = window.open(
    "file:///C:/Users/Darren%20Blount/OneDrive/COUNTDOWN/5_timer.html", 
"DescriptiveWindowName", 'height=30000,width=40000, left=40000, resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes, status=yes');


var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", 
"December"];
var d = new Date();
var currentMonth = monthNames[d.getMonth()];

var DayNames = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
"12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", 
"24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"];
var g = new Date();
var currentDay = DayNames[g.getDay()];



var wednesday /* Havenot worked into code*/= [
    // Daily Bell Schedule
    ['Oct 30, 2018 7:50:49', 'Oct 30, 2018 8:00:49'],
    //AAP
    ['Oct 30, 2018 9:29:49', 'Oct 30, 2018 9:34:49'],
    //1st Block - 2nd Block
    ['Oct 30, 2018 9:58:49', 'Oct 30, 2018 10:03:49'],
    //2nd Block - 1st Half 3rd Block

    ['Oct 30, 2018 11:49:49', 'Oct 30, 2018 11:37:49'],
    //1st Lunch - 3rd Block
    ['Oct 30, 2018 12:02:49', 'Oct 30, 2018 12:07:49'],
    //2nd Lunch - 2nd Half of 3rd Block
    ['Oct 30, 2018 12:42:49', 'Oct 30, 2018 12:47:49'],
    //3rd Block - 4th Block
    ['Oct 30, 2018 13:36:49', 'Oct 30, 2018 13:41:49']
];

const schedule /*Everyday*/= [
    ['Sep 11, 2018 7:50:49', 'Sep 11, 2018 8:00:49'],
    //AAP
    ['Sep 11, 2018 9:29:49', 'Sep 11, 2018 9:34:49'],
    //1st Block - 2nd Block
    ['Sep 11, 2018 9:58:49', 'Sep 11, 2018 10:03:49'],
    //2nd Block - 1st Half 3rd Block
    ['Sep 11, 2018 11:49:49', 'Sep 11, 2018 11:37:49'],
    //1st Lunch - 3rd Block
    ['Sep 11, 2018 12:02:49', 'Sep 11, 2018 12:07:49'],
    //2nd Lunch - 2nd Half of 3rd Block
    ['Sep 11, 2018 12:42:49', 'Sep 11, 2018 12:47:49'],
    //3rd Block - 4th Block
    ['Sep 11, 2018 1:36:49', 'Sep 11, 2018 1:41:49']
];


const schedule = [
    [currentMonth + currentDay + '2019 13:40:00', currentMonth + currentDay 
+ '2019 14:30:00']
]

for(let i=0; i<schedule.length; i++){
// pull them straight into Date objects
const startDate = new Date(schedule[i][0]);
const endDate = new Date(schedule[i][1]);

// Make a new Date for setting it for today, then set the hours based off 
the schedule
let startTime = new Date();
startTime.setHours(startDate.getHours(), startDate.getMinutes(), 
startDate.getSeconds());
let endTime = new Date();
endTime.setHours(endDate.getHours(), endDate.getMinutes(), 
endDate.getSeconds());

// Easier way to just get the ms and then the same check
const currentMs = Date.now();
if(endTime.valueOf() > currentMs && currentMs >= startTime.valueOf() ){
    initializeClock('clockdiv', endDate);
      openRequestedPopup();
        myStopFunction();
        setInterval(function(){window.location.reload(5);}, 306000);
        setTimeout(function () { windowObjectReference.close();}, 305000);
        }
}
```

Comment: Please include the code where you're pulling the array. Also look at [the documentation for the `getDay` method of a `Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay).

Comment: October 30th 2018 was a Tuesday...

Comment: As @HereticMonkey says, you can check if `new Date().getDay() == 3`.

Comment: Can we see an attempt pleasae

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result , below option of getting current day using getDay()
(starts with Sunday - 0 and for Wednesday it is 3)

```js
var d = new Date();
var today = d.getDay();

var wednesday = [
    // Daily Bell Schedule
    ['Oct 30, 2018 7:50:49', 'Oct 30, 2018 8:00:49'],
    //AAP
    ['Oct 30, 2018 9:29:49', 'Oct 30, 2018 9:34:49'],
    //1st Block - 2nd Block
    ['Oct 30, 2018 9:58:49', 'Oct 30, 2018 10:03:49'],
    //2nd Block - 1st Half 3rd Block

    ['Oct 30, 2018 11:49:49', 'Oct 30, 2018 11:37:49'],
    //1st Lunch - 3rd Block
    ['Oct 30, 2018 12:02:49', 'Oct 30, 2018 12:07:49'],
    //2nd Lunch - 2nd Half of 3rd Block
    ['Oct 30, 2018 12:42:49', 'Oct 30, 2018 12:47:49'],
    //3rd Block - 4th Block
    ['Oct 30, 2018 13:36:49', 'Oct 30, 2018 13:41:49']
];

var everyday = [
    ['Sep 11, 2018 7:50:49', 'Sep 11, 2018 8:00:49'],
    //AAP
    ['Sep 11, 2018 9:29:49', 'Sep 11, 2018 9:34:49'],
    //1st Block - 2nd Block
    ['Sep 11, 2018 9:58:49', 'Sep 11, 2018 10:03:49'],
    //2nd Block - 1st Half 3rd Block
    ['Sep 11, 2018 11:49:49', 'Sep 11, 2018 11:37:49'],
    //1st Lunch - 3rd Block
    ['Sep 11, 2018 12:02:49', 'Sep 11, 2018 12:07:49'],
    //2nd Lunch - 2nd Half of 3rd Block
    ['Sep 11, 2018 12:42:49', 'Sep 11, 2018 12:47:49'],
    //3rd Block - 4th Block
    ['Sep 11, 2018 1:36:49', 'Sep 11, 2018 1:41:49']
];

if(today ===3){
  console.log("Wednesday", wednesday)
}else{
  console.log("not wednesday", everyday)
}
```